# Deployment to Heroku (using PHP) results in content not loading

Tags: php, heroku

I'm developing a website in `PHP`, and everything is working perfectly on `localhost` (I'm using `WAMP`). Pushed my code to `GitHub` (which is connected to my `Heroku` environment), and when I go visit the website on the `Heroku domain`, almost everything that relies on `PHP` is blank.

The weirdest part is that I'm still able to log in, with credentials that exist in my database. So I'm not led to believe that this is an issue with my database. What's also weird is that when I inspect my `homepage` (after logging in) there's no HTML for a large part of my page elements, even though the code loads just fine on `localhost`. The common factor with the HTML not loading, is that they're elements that interact with the `PHP` on some level; either entirely or for a small portion.

I don't know what could be wrong, so I'm at a loss on what to ask, specifically. Could it be the `PHP?` Something with `Heroku?` I'd love to know if anyone else has had this issue at all, too.

Thanks in advance, and have a great one!

Answer (score 0):

So I am answering my own question because thankfully I was able to find a solution. Basically, what I can conclude is that Apache is a little more forgiving than Heroku's servers. So if you have any open divs, or otherwise wonky HTML (which I had), Heroku will just give up on showing you any of it. In short, make sure your HTML is organized and closed where it needs to be. No dangling divs, and always close your head and body tags!